# How do I remove error message when saving my PHP file XAMPP? (MAC)

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have been trying to find answers. I'm using text wrangler for mac. When I try to save theres an error. I put my XAMPP on my application folder and I was thinking that it was in the application folder and you can't make any changes. I need to know how to save it. By the way when i move something it keeps asking me to authenticate. Help!

Comment: what error? produced by the web server? or the IDE or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me before as well. Most likely you need to change the directory permissions. Go to '/Applications/XAMPP/', and change the permissions of the `htdocs` directory. [Here's how.](http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/21/change-file-permissions-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

you just don't have authority save it. if you want to do this, pls give the authority to text wrangler.
you can try this in terminal.

```
sudo open filename -a applicationname.app
```

for example:

```
sudo open test.php -a Coda.app
```

or you can try to change the folder's access permission by using **chmod** in terminal
for example:

```
chmod 774 foldername
```

Comment: You're going to have to do this with every file, every time. You'd rather change the permissions of the whole `htdocs` directory.

Comment: you are right. i just think changing permission maybe cause some security risks.

Comment: XAMPP is local-only, plus you can also enable a password for PMA, the htdocs folder, etc. once you're in the admin.